# Variational Derivative of Geodesic Ball Volume by Metric Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry

Relevant Article: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-20/issue-4/The-volume-of-a-small-geodesic-ball-of-a-Riemannian/10.1307/mmj/1029001150.full

From this paper on the finding of a series expansion formula for the volume of Geodesic balls on a Riemannian Manifold, the following formula is used:

$$S (r) =\int_{S^{n-1}(1)} r^{n-1} \omega_{1...n} (\text{exp}(ru)) \, du $$

$S(r)$ denotes the desired volume of the sphere at some point in an analytic Riemannian manifold, $S^{n-1}(1)$ is the volume of an $r=1$, n-1 sphere, $\omega_{1...n}$ is the volume element (alternatively $\omega = \sqrt{\text{det}(g)}$), and $\text{exp}(ru)$ is a factor introduced by a change of variables that utilizes the exponential mapping ($j:S^{n-1}(1) \rightarrow \text{exp}(S^{n-1}(r))$ with $j(u) = \text{exp}(ru)$). I suggest reading the paper to see where this formula comes from more precisely(section 2 and 3 especially).

From these sections, my question is how to find the variational/functional derivative of the volume function in terms of the metric tensor.

$$\frac{\delta S(r)}{\delta g^{ab}} = \text{??}$$.

Using the series expansion one can find the variational derivative of each term fine as the Riemann Tensor's derivatives and scalars can be written out explicitly, but having a general formula similar to equation 9 or 10 from section 3 is what I'm looking for.

Fairly lost besides the brute force term by term approach.

Comment: For fixed $r>0$, the variational derivative $\frac{\delta S(r)}{\delta g}$ will have to be expressed as an integral operator, since $S(r)$ depends nonlocally on $g$.

Comment: @Kajelad That's a start :') Thanks

Comment: Is possible to do $\frac{\delta S(r)}{\delta g^{ab}}=\int_{S^{n-1}(1)} r^{n-1}\exp(ru) \frac{\delta\omega_{1...n}}{\delta g^{ab}} \, du=\frac12\int_{S^{n-1}(1)} r^{n-1}\exp(ru) \omega_{1...n} g_{ab}\, du$? not sure if it makes sense just following what get from wikipedia about gravitational [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein-Hilbert_action#Variation_of_the_determinant)

Comment: @Dabed hmmm the thing I'm hooked up on is if $r$ can be ignored like that. Since the integral is non-local for the metric, $g^{ab}$ becomes dependent on $r$ which probably requires some weird parameterization. I do like this article though thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of a possible approach to deriving an ODE that $S(r)$ satisfies in terms of the variation of the curvature tensor. The idea is that if $\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n$ are the standard coordinate vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then
$$
J = (\exp_p)_*\partial_i
$$
are Jacobi fields. They satisfy
$$
g_{ij} = J_i\cdot J_j,
$$
where $g_{ij}\,dx^i\,dx^j = (\exp_p)^*g$, and
$$
J_i(0) = 0,\ \nabla_rJ_i(0) = \partial_i
$$
and
$$
\nabla_r\nabla_rJ_i = K(\partial_r, J)\partial_r.
$$
Now the idea is to write the volume of the ball in terms of the Jacobi fields and differentiating it (possibly twice) with respect to the variational parameter. For a fixed value of the parameter, the Christoffel symbols will satisfy equation coming from the fact that radial lines are geodesics. This will in turn give formulas for the variation of the Christoffel symbols, which will be needed.

You might need to calculate $S'(r)$ instead.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

For $\gamma_\tau (\lambda)$ being a family of geodesics restricted by the volume $S$ and $J := \lambda\partial_i $ being an attached Jacobi field, the idea would be to take the repeated derivatives of the Jacobi equation?

Then we can take any number of derivatives really (not just two) which creates a set of diff. eqs. in the Riemann tensor and metric according to the substitution $g_{ij} = J_i \cdot J_j$. Perhaps one takes the trace of each DE to find the vol. element. I think I understand the process but I'm probably naive in thinking this would be easy

Comment: ($J:=\lambda\partial_i$ in normal coordinates).

Comment: I think you understand what I’m suggesting and encourage you to try it. I might be able to post more details.

Comment: The expression I got for the volume element utilizes geodesic polar coordinates such that $g(\partial_r, \partial_r) = 1$ and $g_(\partial_r, \partial_{i\neq r}) = 0$. The use of geodesic polar lets you separate a radial component easily which is super useful for the exponential mapping between $S^{n-1} (r)$ and $S^{n-1} (1)$.
$$d\omega = \left | \bigwedge (J_i) \wedge \partial_r \right | dr dx_i$$

Where $J_i$ is essentially the same as how you defined it (in the polar coords).

Comment: There were some details that you said you could write eventually I think they could be pedagogical to me at least so I would be interested if you feel like writing them.